# Getting list of corrupted file from folder and its sub folder

Tags: shell-script, corruption, bzip2

I have following directory structure

```
folder
└── 01
    ├── test1
        └── abc.bz2
        └── asd.bz2
    ├── test2
        └── 546.bz2
        └── alsj.bz2
    ├── test3
        └── aewr.bz2
        └── hlk.bz2
    └── test4
        └── oiqw.bz2
        └── abc.bz2
└── 02
    ├── test1
    ├── test2
    ├── test3
    └── test4
└── 03
    ├── test1
    ├── test2
    ├── test3
    └── test4
.
.
└── 31
```

all `test1..4` directory contain large number of bzip files which is copied from remote server. I know the command `bzip2 -t <filename.bz2>` to check whether file is corrupted or not, but I need to check all corrupted files from above folder structure. So How to write shell script to get list of all corrupted files ?
I'm new to shell script and Linux so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `find` with `-exec`:

```
find . -name '*bz2' -exec sh -c 'bzip2 -t "$0" 2>/dev/null || echo "$0 is corrupted"' {} \;
```

From `man find`:

```
  -exec command ;
          Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
          arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
          an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}'
          is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere
          it occurs in the arguments to the command [...]
```

So, the `find` command above, will look for all files ending with `bz2`, and launch a little `sh` script on each of them. The `{}` is replaced by each file name found. This is passed as the 1st parameter (`$0`) to the `sh` script which will run `bzip -t` on it and complain if it fails. The `2>/dev/null` discards any other error messages to keep things clean.

---

Alternatively, you can use the shell. If you're using `bash`, enable the `globstar` option to make `**` recurse into subdirectories and check each bzip file:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in folder/**/*bz; do bzip2 -t "$file" || echo "$file is corrupted"; done
```

Comment: thank you. how to redirect all list of corrupted files to corrupted.txt

Comment: @arzyfex just add `> corrupted.txt` at the end of either command. So, `find ... > corrupted.txt` or `for file ... > corrupted.txt`.

Comment: @ terdon : when I executed your command that is `find folder -name '*bz2' -exec sh -c "bzip2 -t {} || echo {}" +`, I got Permission denied error at all the files. Do I need to set permission to run this command ?

Comment: @arzyfex no, I just need to be more careful when posting. Sorry, I had made a mistake. Try the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below script.

```
cd folder
find -name "*.bz2" > bzipfiles
for i in `cat bzipfiles`
do
    bzip2 -t $i
    if [ $? == '0']
    then
        echo "$i file is not corrupted"
    else
        echo "$i file is corrupted"
        echo "$i" >> corruptedfile_list
    fi
done
```

Please find corrupted file list on `corruptedfile_list`.

Comment: This will break if any of the file names contain whitespace. Use `while IFS= read -r file; do ...; done < bzipfiles` to avoid that.